# sum of this series: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n^2-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I am trying to calculate the sum of this infinite series after having read the series chapter of my textbook: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n^2-1}$$

my steps:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n^2-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{4n^2-1}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n^2-1}=..help..=sum$$

I am lacking some important properties, I feel I am coming to the right step and cannot spit that out..

Comment: Hint: Write your rational functions as a linear combination of fractions with denominator being a linear function.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238728/finding-summation/238792#238792

Comment: @doniyor taking $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4n+2}\right)$ in the result posted in Elias's link you get $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding sum $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{4i^2-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238728/finding-sum-sum-i-1n-frac14i2-1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Partial Fraction decomposition:$$\frac{1}{4n^2-1}=\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}=\frac12[\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}]$$
You must then compute the closed form of
$$\sum_{n=1}^k[\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}]$$
Can you do that?
Note that
$$\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{2n-1}=\frac11+\frac13+...+\frac1{2k-1}=\frac1{2\cdot 0+1}+\frac1{2\cdot 1+1}+...+\frac1{2(k-1)+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{2n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac1{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 0+1}-\frac1{2k+1}$$

Comment: can you pls expand this step? $\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{2n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{2n+1}$

Comment: @doniyor Sure I can.

Answer (score 18):

Note $\frac{1}{4n^2-1}=\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}={\frac{1}{2}}\times\frac{(2n+1)-(2n-1)}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}={\frac{1}{2}}\times[\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}]$ for $n\in\mathbb N.$

Let for $k\in\mathbb N,$ $S_k=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{4n^2-1}$ $\implies S_k={\frac{1}{2}}\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{k}\left[\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right].$ Thus for $k=1,2,...$

$S_1={\frac{1}{2}}\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{1}\left[\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right]=\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{3})$

$S_2={\frac{1}{2}}\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{2}\left[\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right]=\frac{1}{2}[(1-\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5})]=\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{5})$

$S_3={\frac{1}{2}}\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{3}\left[\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right]=\frac{1}{2}[(1-\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5})+(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7})]=\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{7})$

...

$S_k=\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{2k+1})$

$\implies\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n^2-1}=\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}S_k=\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: great, thanks Sugata

Comment: You're most welcome.

Answer (score 8):

Or we want to compute it fastly and use the formula
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^2-x^2}=\frac1{2x^2}-\frac{\pi\cot\,\pi x}{2x}$$
where $x=\frac{1}{2}$ because 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4k^2-1}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}$$
[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141470/find-the-sum-of-sum-1-k2-a2-when-0a1/143157#143157) you may find more information about this precious way.

Comment: @doniyor: you're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

This is an easy problem by using Fourier's serie of $|\sin(x)|$. So,
$|\sin(x)|=\dfrac2\pi-\dfrac4\pi\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos(2nx)}{4n^2-1} $. By taking $x=0$, we obtain:

$0=\dfrac2\pi-\dfrac4\pi\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{4n^2-1} $.

So,

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{4n^2-1}=\dfrac12$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Work on $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{4k^2-1}$ and take its limit when $n\to\infty$. Note that $$\frac{1}{4n^2-1}=\frac{1}{2(2n-1)}-\frac{1}{2(2n+1)}$$

Comment: Why don't you experts leave such problems for beginners like us ? :(

Comment: @SugataAdhya: Dear Sugata, I am not an expert. I am a teacher and like to help others in Maths. That's it. We are here to help eachother in learning Maths well. :-)

Comment: :), yeah, but you guys are doing wonderful job here.. thanks again for all you

Comment: Yes, as dear doniyor says, you're doing a wonderful job here! +