# How do I calculate the sum of this infinite series? $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n^{2}-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Could someone please help me with how do I calculate the sum of the $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n^{2}-1}$$ infinite series? I see that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{4n^{2}-1}=0$$ so the series is convergent based on the Cauchy's convergence test. But how do I calculate the sum? Thank you.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/265277?rq=1

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize I can put latex code in the search bar. I'm gonna do it next time. Thank you everyone for the answers!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**. By a fraction decomposition, one gets
$$
\frac{2}{4n^{2}-1}=\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}
$$ then one may use a [telescoping sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html).

Answer (score 4):

Since$$\frac1{4n^2-1}=\frac1{(2n-1)(2n+1)}=\frac12\left(\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{2n+1}\right),$$your series is a telescopic series.

Answer (score 3):

Your justification for the convergence to he series needs work (having a limit of zero of the summand does not imply the sum converges!), it does however converge a priori by noting that 
$$
\frac{1}{4n^2-1}=O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
$$
So it converges by the $p$-test.

You may also use the partial fraction decomposition noted in the other answers and compute the telescoping series, showing that it converges.

Comment: Your equivalent is wrong as written. The $\sim$ has a specific meaning, and here you're missing the constant $4$ on the RHS.

Comment: i meant asymptotically equivalent to. what does it mean?

Comment: $a_n \sim_{n\to\infty} b_n$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n} =1 $ (that's the simple definition; the actual one, equivalent when $b_n$ can't cancel, is that $a_n-b_n = o(b_n)$)

Comment: I see, I will amend the above then

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{4n^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)$$