# How to do these very abstract summation simplifications?

Tags: summation

For instance, I have these questions for an assignment.

$ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} (n-k)2^{k}$

$ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac 1 {4k^{2}-1}$

Answer (score 1):

For sums that include $ka^k$, one trick is to substitute
$$ka^k=a\left[\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}x^k\right]_{x=a}.$$

The first sum is
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-k)2^k
& = n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k2^k \\
&=n(2^n-1)-2\left[\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k\right]_{x=2} \\
& =n(2^n-1)-2\left[\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\right]_{x=2} \\
&=n(2^n-1)-2\left[\frac{nx^{n-1}(x-1)-x^n+1}{(x-1)^2}\right]_{x=2} \\
&=2^{n+1}-n-2.
\end{align}

For the second sum, refer to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/265327/495620). You can write the summands as a sum of simple fractions
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{4k^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2k-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2k+1}\right]$$
and note that this is a telescopic cum: the $k$-th term in the first sum is  equal to the $(k+1)$-th term in the second sum, so all terms cancel except two:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{4k^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\left[1-\frac{1}{2n-1}\right]=\frac{n-1}{2n-1}.$$