# Studying the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n^2-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Study the character of the following number series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n^2-1}$$
and in the case of convergence also determine its sum.

**Solution**:

To study its convergence, we can try to express each term in a simpler form. Notice that $4n^2 - 1$ can be factored as $(2n + 1)(2n - 1)$, which suggests using partial fraction decomposition(*). We can write:

$$\frac{1}{4n^2 - 1} = \frac{1}{(2n + 1)(2n - 1)} = \frac{1}{2(2n - 1)} - \frac{1}{2(2n + 1)}$$

Now, the given series becomes a telescoping series after decomposition:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2(2n - 1)} - \frac{1}{2(2n + 1)}\right)$$

When we expand this series, a lot of terms will cancel out, leaving only the first and last terms:

$$\left(\frac{1}{2(2\cdot1 - 1)} - \frac{1}{2(2\cdot1 + 1)}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2(2\cdot2 - 1)} - \frac{1}{2(2\cdot2 + 1)}\right) + \dots$$

$$= \left(\frac{1}{2(1)} - \frac{1}{2(3)}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2(3)} - \frac{1}{2(5)}\right) + \dots + \left(\frac{1}{2(n) - 1} - \frac{1}{2(n + 1) + 1}\right)$$

As we can see, each term cancels with the next term except for the first term and the last term:

$$\left(\frac{1}{2(1)} - \frac{1}{2(3)}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2(n) - 1} - \frac{1}{2(n + 1) + 1}\right) + \dots$$

$$= \frac{1}{2(1)} - \frac{1}{2(n + 1) + 1}$$

As $n$ approaches infinity, the second term approaches zero. Thus, the sum of the series converges to $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

(*)

$$\frac{1}{(2n + 1)(2n - 1)} = \frac{A}{2n + 1} + \frac{B}{2n - 1}$$

To find $A$ and $B$, we'll multiply both sides by the denominator $(2n + 1)(2n - 1)$ to clear the fractions:

$$1 = A(2n - 1) + B(2n + 1)$$

Expanding the right side:

$$1 = 2An - A + 2Bn + B$$

Now, we can equate the coefficients of like terms on both sides:

For $n$ terms:
$$2A + 2B = 0$$

For the constant terms:
$$-A + B = 1$$

We have a system of two equations:

1. $2A + 2B = 0$
2. $-A + B = 1$

From equation 1, we can solve for $A$:
$$2A = -2B$$
$$A = -B$$

Now, substitute $A = -B$ into equation 2:
$$-(-B) + B = 1$$
$$B + B = 1$$
$$2B = 1$$
$$B = \frac{1}{2}$$

Substitute $B = \frac{1}{2}$ back into $A = -B$:
$$A = -\frac{1}{2}$$

So, we have found that $A = -\frac{1}{2}$ and $B = \frac{1}{2}$.

Therefore, the partial fraction decomposition of the function is:

$$\frac{1}{(2n + 1)(2n - 1)} = -\frac{1}{2(2n + 1)} + \frac{1}{2(2n- 1)}$$

> Is there another way to solve the series?

Comment: Fourier series usually helps in these situations.

Comment: @MatthewCassell Thank you so much for your reply. No I can't use it.

Comment: Are you looking for an easier method, or just another method? What other methods can you allow?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265277/sum-of-this-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac14n2-1), with answers invoking Fourier series and infinite partial fractions for the trigonometric functions

Comment: @DS Hi, very kind. I search for an easier method-

Comment: @KBDave Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way by renumeration

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{4 n^2-1}=\frac{1}{2} \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{2 n-1}-\frac{1}{2 n+1}\right)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{2} \left(\sum _{n=0}^k \frac{1}{2 n+1}-\sum _{n=1}^k \frac{1}{2 n+1}\right) = \frac{1}{2} $$

Comment: I like this. +1